# Ember.js Route: How to avoid infinite loop when refreshing parent route from child setupController

Tags: ember.js

I have two nested routes, `projects` and `projects/project`. Whenever I open a `project`, I would like the `projects` route to be refreshed.

What I am doing know is to call a controller function during the `setupController` hook (that will end up calling `refresh` in the `projects` route). Something like this:

```
  // project route
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('projects').send('search');
    controller.set('model', model)
  }

  // projects controller
  actions: {
    search: function() {
      // do other things
      this.send('refreshModel');

    }
  }

  // projects route
  actions: {
    refreshModel: function() {
      this.refresh();
    }
  }
```

The problem is that, when the `refresh` function is called, it not only refreshes the current route, but also all the children routes, meaning that this `setupController` hook will be executed again, creating this infinite loop.

Is there a way to make Ember refresh just the current route, ignoring its children?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To answer directly, there is no way to only refresh the parent route. You might, however, be able to just reload the model and still get the behaviour you need.

See the relevant API documentation for [`DS.Model#reload`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_reload).